# Libusb control transfer error

Tags: libusb

I run this

```
libusb_control_transfer(usb_handle,0xA1, 1, 0, 1, buf, 0x800, 1000);
```

and get error

> libusb:error [submit_control_transfer] submiturb failed error -1 errno=2

What does that mean? I couldn't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: -1 is `libusb_error::LIBUSB_ERROR_IO` and errno=2 is a linux error code, means `ENOENT /* No such file or directory */` Do not forget use libusb_detach_kernel_driver() and libusb_claim_interface().

Answer (score 0):

You can save the return value of libusb_control_transfer() and print it using libusb_error_name(). Example:

int retControl = libusb_control_transfer(usb_handle,0xA1, 1, 0, 1, buf, 0x800, 1000);
printf("libusb_control_transfer error: %s", libusb_error_name(retControl));